# Android App can't write data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to build an android app that displays info about books (using Google books API).I have recently added firebase to the app.

At this moment I can log in or register to the app(new users appear in FB console), I can search for books (with search view) and I have added a button for every book listed in the ListView that is created from the query.

Next, I added functionality to the button as it follows: the button (if pressed) should add the current book(in the Listview) to FireBase in the current user's "library".
I have written this code in my custom AdapterClass so I can add the current book (from the ListView) like this:

**CustomAdapter Class:**

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookObject> implements View.OnClickListener {
BookObject mCurrentBook;
public BookAdapter(Activity context, List<BookObject> books) {
    super(context, 0, books); // 2nd par is 0 because we inflate manually
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
    }

    BookObject currentBook = getItem(position);
    mCurrentBook = currentBook;

    TextView TitleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Title_text_view);
    TitleTextView.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

   ...
    ImageView ThumbnailImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_image_id);
    Picasso.with(UserActivity.mMainActivity).load(currentBook.getImageURL()).into(ThumbnailImageView);

    Button SaveBookbutton = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    SaveBookbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return listItemView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();

    DatabaseReference bookRef = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_BOOKS) // this constant is "books"
            .child(uid);

    DatabaseReference pushRef = bookRef.push();
    String pushId = pushRef.getKey();
    mCurrentBook.setPushId(pushId);
    pushRef.setValue(mCurrentBook);

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
}
```

**Build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

 dependencies {
 ...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Firebase rules and Data Tab**

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
         }
}
```

[image: Data tab in Firebase]

**When I press the button(on a certain BookObject displayed in ListView I get the toast message yet my Data Tab in Firebase doesn't update.(therefore doesn't add the book to the database). *What am I doing wrong*?**

*Note:(after the books have been displayed and before I am able to press the button)I get following notification in Android Studio:*

```
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Gist with BookObject.java:
[Gist with BookObject.java](https://gist.github.com/catalinghita8/d7d659d157e78e3dd099584a7060fd5a)

*Thank you for any interest in my question and for any help as well.*

Comment: When you add the data to the database, did you check whether it is added or not?

Comment: My only way of checking was checking the Data Tab in Firebase(which looks like in the photo every time).How can I do a better check?

Comment: That's not what i meant. I mean do you have any data at all in the database? If you don't. You can't do anything at all.

Comment: I don't have any data. I thought that child nodes of rootnode(which is the app) would be created automatically when requested.(as I read on a website) .Therefore do I need to create a child node called "books" first?

Comment: Yes. Either you enter the data manually to the firebase or you need to create add function. You have to add data first before you retrieving the data.

Comment: add a onSucessListener to the pushRef.setValue(mCurrentBook), something like that pushRef.setValue(mCurrentBook).addonSucessListener(), and onsucess method add the Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and see if the sucess method fires

Comment: @UmarZaii I am not trying to retrieve data. I am trying to ADD data- see code in Onclick method in bookadapter (used setValue so therefore I am adding data)

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry for misunderstanding. Can you add BookObject class code in the question pls.

Comment: @Bruno Ferreira I am adding it right now.

Comment: @umarZaii posted gist in post (BookObject.java)

Comment: I think your object is empty. That's why you add nothing to the database.

Comment: ?? Where is the code?

Comment: @UmarZaii now is posted. Why do you think it's empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150534/discussion-between-umarzaii-and-catalin-ghita).

Comment: @BrunoFerreira the toast message still gets delievered. therefore the adding procedure works. Yet why my FB database still remains empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable in the `CustomAdapterClass`

```
private String mTitle;
private String mSubTitle;
private String mAuthors;
```

Retrieve all the data and store them in the string

```
BookObject currentBook = getItem(position);
mTitle = currentBook.getTitle();
mSubTitle = currentBook.getSubTitle();
mAuthors = currentBook.getAuthors();
```

And use code below in `OnClick`method

```
DatabaseReference pushRef = bookRef.push();
String pushId = pushRef.getKey();
mCurrentBook.setPushId(pushId);
pushRef.child("Title").setValue(mTitle);
pushRef.child("SubTitle").setValue(mSubTitle);
pushRef.child("Authors").setValue(mAuthors);
```